# How to send automatic mail to a person if certain event occured?

Tags: android

I am implementing a temperature sensing system project. I want to write a data on file and in temperature field if it exceed a certain temp then I want to send a mail to a user automatically. How can i do it?

Comment: I am able to sense the temperature and getting output on a file but as soon as  it exceeds above a value i want to inform to user by mail or sms i dont know how to do that.

Comment: This question does not show much research effort..

Answer (score 0):

These are the links which will help you in sending email directlty from your android app-

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429828/sending-e-mail-directly-from-an-android-application)
[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)